# Php like jagged array initialisation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

We have in PHP the jagged array declaration is like this:

```
<?php
$classmates = array ('Name' => array ('Bob', 'Jane', 'Jill'),
                    'Age' => array (18, 20, 23));

echo $classmates['Name'][1] . ' is ' . $classmates['Age'][1] . ' years old!';
?>
```

can we do same initialization of array in C#??

If yes than how? also tell me if it is possible to do with data type List?

Comment: The right way to do this will be to use a list of class objects.

Answer (score 2):

Well, literally speaking, you could do something like this in C#:

```
    var arr = new Array[] { 
        new[] {"Bob", "Jane", "Jill"},
        new[] { 18,20,23 }};
```

I will say that it's probably not going to be a good idea.  In C#, it's much better form to say something like this:

```
var arr = new[] { 
    new Person {Name = "Bob", Age = 18},
    new Person {Name = "Jane", Age = 20},
    new Person {Name = "Jill", Age = 23}};
```

or, if you're not into creating an actual Person class, you can use an anonymous class:

```
var arr = new[] { 
    new {Name = "Bob", Age = 18},
    new {Name = "Jane", Age = 20},
    new {Name = "Jill", Age = 23}};
```

What course you take depends on how you'll use the array, but suffice it to say that the first usage is not, for most use cases, considered to be a best practice.